# Azure Scale Sets in 1 Resource Group

Tags: azure

I am trying to move a Scale Set with MANAGED DISKS into an already created Subnet in another Resource Group. IT moves the Scale Set to the VNET of that Resource Group but NOT to the Subnet. Please help......
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Could you edit your question to say what you've tried already? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use the same Vnet?

Comment: Yes, I know that seems simple but I think I got up in the confusion of moving Scale Sets..I found out the hard way that Scale Sets HAS to have unmanaged disks to move them......Thanks

Comment: @Mike yes, managed disks are not enable to move, we can re-deploy vmss with this image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Managed disks are **not** enable to move.

In your scenario, we can use your vmss' image to deploy another VMss with another subnet.
We can **create managed image** from managed disks vm, then use this image to create VMSS.